# ASP.Net MVC auto slugify Routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have this code in my Controller:

```
string APIBaseurl = "https://sub.domain.de/";
    [Route("VerseExkurs/Technologien/{technologie}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Details(string technologie)
    {
        TechnologieRootobject TechnologieInfo = new TechnologieRootobject();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //Passing service base url  
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(APIBaseurl);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            //Define request data format  
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  
            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("items/technologien/" + technologie + "?access_token=token");

            //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                var TechnologieResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list  
                TechnologieInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TechnologieRootobject>(TechnologieResponse);

            }
            //returning the employee list to view  
            return View(TechnologieInfo.data);
        }
    }
```

But the Problem is, the "{technologie}" Variable is in some Cases with Spaces. Is there any way to automatically convert spaces in underdashes?

Answer (score 0):

You have few options.

1. Utilize string.Replace() method

```
    HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("items/technologien/" + technologie.Replace(" ", "_") + "?access_token=token");
```

2. Write a helper function that returns correct string

```
string removeSpaceFromString(string inputString)
{
     return inputString.Replace(" ", "_"); // or some other method of doing that
}
```

Comment: Seems like this question's title, then the last thing they person asks is a little out of sync.